# Empty fragment when I reload it

Tags: android, android-fragments

Basically, I have a `MainActivity` that displays different Fragments when clicked on menu options.

`Stats`, is a `Fragment` that displays 4 fragments in it. Every time it is displayed, will replace 4 `FrameLayouts` on the view.

The first time work perfectly, but when I change to different fragments and get back in Stats, it seems not to replace the `FrameLayouts` to `Fragments`...

`Stats` as follows:

```
public class StatsFragment extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;

    private MoreSoldBarChartFragment moreSold = MoreSoldBarChartFragment.newInstance(null);
    private MoreIncomeBarChartFragment moreIncome = MoreIncomeBarChartFragment.newInstance(null);
    private SoldLineChartFragment soldLine = SoldLineChartFragment.newInstance(null);
    private IncomeLineChartFragment incomeLine = IncomeLineChartFragment.newInstance(null);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);

        initViews();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void initViews() {
        replace(moreIncome, R.id.moreIncome);
        replace(moreSold, R.id.moreSold);
        replace(soldLine, R.id.soldLine);
        replace(incomeLine, R.id.incomeLine);
    }

    private void replace(Fragment fragmentToReplace, int container) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(container, fragmentToReplace);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public static StatsFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
        StatsFragment fragment = new StatsFragment();
        fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `getChildFragmentManager()` to display Fragments within Fragments:

```
private void replace(Fragment fragmentToReplace, int container) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(container, fragmentToReplace);
    ft.commit();
}
```

As that ensures that the Fragments are properly handled when the parent's state is changed (i.e., when it is swapped with another Fragment and back). When you use `getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()`, Fragments have no idea that these Fragments are related and can't restore the Fragments.